# Windows Phone 8 app cannot launch after renaming the project(PhoneGap)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I finally finished my project and the last step for me is to change the project name(HelloCordova) to the real name.

I performed the renaming action via Visual Studio 2012 and deleted all files which had the old name in.
Then rebuilt successfully, the app has been deployed onto my mobile(Windows Phone 8), it launches(coz I saw a black screen for a few seconds, then the app exited.)

Have performed search action via File Explorer as well under the project wp8 folder as well and changed all old names.

Can anyone help???

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was:

Although I performed a "search all" action to rename the project, the visual studio doesn't check the project file itself(which makes sense as it is opened by the VS and cannot be changed while it's opened).

So the solution is:
Close the project/solution, and open the .proj file in whatever text editor you like,
find the project name in it and change it to the new name.

Job done :)

I hope it helps for people who meet the same problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't had deleted old files :(
and if you have a old named backup or if you can bring old files, open it, and just do renaming in properties and wmappmanifest.xml.

Comment: I did renaming in wmappmanifest.xml, those old files were only under obj folders which were generated, so they should not be the cause of my problem.

Comment: Do you have any utf-8 chars in its name?

Comment: Hi ardaozkal, no, I don't have

Comment: And what was the files that you deleted? (english failed :) )

Comment: files under obj folders with names containing HelloCordova. They were really just generated files, really :)